# Linux bash script to copy files by list

Tags: bash

I'm new in bash and I need a help please. I have a file call list.txt containing pattern like

```
1210
1415
1817
```

What I want to do is to write a bash script which will copy all file in my current directory which name contain that pattern towards a new directory called `toto`.

Example of my file in the current directory :

```
1210_ammm.txt
1415_xdffmslk.txt
1817_lsmqlkksk.txt
201247_kksjdjdjd.txt
```

The goal is to copy `1210_ammm.txt`, `1415_xdffmslk.txt`, `1817_lsmqlkksk.txt` to `toto`.

---

<sup>*Transferred from an ['answer'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38724256).*</sup>

My list.txt and toto directory are in my current directory. That is what I try

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p; do # read my list file 

  for i in `find -name $p -type f` # find all file match the pattern

   do

   cp $i toto # copy all files find into toto

   done

done < partB.txt
```

I don't have an error but it doesn't do the job.

Comment: What did you try? Please remember SO community is not a free coding service!

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to implement :

```
read tokens from an input file
for each token
   search the files whose name contain said token
   for each file found
     copy it to toto
```

To read tokens from the input file, you can use a [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) command in a `while` loop (and the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) generally, and [Bash FAQ 24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) specifically.

To search files whose name contain a string, you can use a for loop and globbing. For example, `for file in ./*test*; do echo $file; done` will print the name of the files in the current directory which contain `test`.

To copy a file, use [`cp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html).

You can check [this ideone sample](https://ideone.com/oKWkDp) for a working implementation.

Comment: Sorry for not asking clearly the questions. This is my first question in the forum

That is what i try but it doesn't work

#!/bin/bash

while read p; do

  for i in `find -name $p -type f`

   do

   cp $i toto

   done

done < list.txt

Comment: @Yao it's OK, the question looks quite clear to me. As others mentioned questions are better received when you include what you tried, but it doesn't stop people from answering either. Could you edit your question to include your current code rather than using a comment? The formatting will make it more readable. Please also describe how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use below script:

```
cp "$(ls | grep -f list.txt)" toto
```

`ls | grep -f list.txt` will grep for the pattern found in `list.txt` in the `ls` output.

`cp` copies the matched files to `toto` directory.

**NOTE:** If `list.txt` and `toto` are not in current directory, provide absolute paths in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this too, I tried @Zaziln's answer, but it gave me errors. I just found a better answer. I think others will be interested too.

```
mapfile -t files < test1.txt
cp -- "${files[@]}" Folder/
```

I found it on this post --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106219/copy-files-from-a-list-to-a-folder#106231